# Which commands or operations can be used to put the cpu under intense load?

Tags: linux, cpu, benchmark

I would like to measure latencies during high cpu usage but I don't have benchmarking tools like stress and I can't install them.

Which operations do you recommend to put the cpu under intense load? 
I would like to reach 100% of cpu usage (I have 700Mhz) without freezing the system. So please don't suggest commands like the fork bomb.

Comment: [Does this help?](http://superuser.com/a/443409)

Comment: I don't have stress installed and I can't run make...

Comment: Wow actually yes. The guy suggests `cat /dev/zero > /dev/null` -> 100% of cpu usage. Love this useless command! @ DevNull, your name appears in the command

Comment: Try `cat /dev/zero`.

Comment: @jimmij with your command I get only 60%

Comment: @narutov6, I posted my comment in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each core:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

or:

```
while :; do :; done
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest looking at [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/443406/how-can-i-produce-high-cpu-load-on-a-linux-server/443409#443409) for some answers.

One approach like you found is:

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/null
[OR]
cat /dev/random > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Compressing video always does it for me, especially since ffmpeg allows you to specify threads.

Something like this (warning, this is an intentional infinite loop):

`while [ yes ] ; do ffmpeg -i samplevideo.mp4 -vcodec libtheora -an -b:v 25000 -g 1 -threads 24 -y output.mkv ; done`

You could also calculate primes. It starts out simple but in the higher range, it'll get yer CPU churning.

```
#include                                                            

int main(void)                                                               
{                                                                            
int i,n,q;                                                                   

for(i=2;i>0;i++) {                                                           
    q=0;                                                                     
    for(n=1;n
```

Compile that with gcc:

gcc primes.c -o primes

And run it.